# c# inserting variable in JSON string by escaping quotes

Tags: c#, json, variables, escaping

I have this JSON double quoted string and I want to insert variable idValue
inside

```
string json = @"  
{
    ""Request"": 
    {
       ""ElementList"": 
        {                                         
        ""id"": ""idValue""                                        
        }                         
     }
 }
```

In regular string this can be done by "+idValue+" ,but how I can do it here when I have
these double quotes? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this :

```
string json = @"  
{
    ""Request"": 
    {
       ""ElementList"": 
        {                                         
        ""id"": """+ idValue + @"""                                        
        }                         
     }
 }";
```

But personally I'd prefer to use a Json library to stringify my stuff.

Edit: Added missing quotation marks in the string.

Comment: Agreed.  I always find I make less silly errors when I serialize objects instead of hand building json.

Comment: This was fast! Right on time, thanks. Mine JSON message is really really big (this was small part of it). I was trying to construct json message using library but I got lost in the middle of it. So I use only this when I send message, but I parse answer from the server with Json library